# Adding "and" to the last author in reference list

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am working on a latex file with elsarticle template. The MWE is shown below.

```
  ‎\documentclass[review]{article}‎  
   \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,raiselinks=true,colorlinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}‎

  \begin{filecontents}{mysuperbib.bib}
  @article{hwang2008heat‎,
   ‎title={Heat transfer with dimple/protrusion arrays in a rectangular duct with a low Reynolds number range}‎,
  ‎author={Hwang‎, ‎Sang Dong and Kwon‎, ‎Hyun Goo and Cho‎, ‎Hyung Hee}‎,
  ‎journal={International journal of heat and fluid flow}‎,
  volume={29}‎,
  number={4}‎,
  ‎pages={916--926}‎,
  ‎year={2008}‎,
  ‎publisher={Elsevier}‎
  }
  @article{hwang2010local‎,
  ‎title={Local heat transfer and thermal performance on periodically dimple-protrusion patterned walls for compact heat exchangers}‎,
  author={Hwang‎, ‎Sang Dong and Kwon‎, ‎Hyun Goo and Cho‎, ‎Hyung Hee}‎,
  journal={Energy}‎,
  volume={35}‎,
  ‎number={12}‎,
  ‎pages={5357--5364}‎,
  ‎year={2010}‎,
  publisher={Elsevier}‎
  }
  \end{filecontents}‎‎

  \begin{document}‎
  \section{Bibliography styles}‎
  In another study‎, ‎Hwang et al‎. ‎\cite{hwang2010local} measured the local distribution of heat transfer coefficient and thermal performance in a channel with a staggered array of dimples and protrusions‎. ‎The studied Reynolds numbers and geometrical characteristics of dimples and protrusions were similar to the previous study‎. ‎Their results showed that various secondary flows were generated from the dimple and protrusion coexist‎. ‎It must be mentioned that the measured local heat transfer coefficients in Hwang et al‎. ‎\cite{hwang2008heat,hwang2010local} studies‎, ‎were used to validate the numerical results in the current research‎. ‎ ‎

  ‎\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
  \bibliography{mysuperbib}
  \end{document}
```

but the problem is in the reference list. I want to generate a reference list with the following configuration:

Hwang, S.D., Kwon, H.G., and Cho, H.H., 2008. Heat transfer with dimple/protrusion arrays in a rectangular duct with a low reynolds number range. International journal of heat and fluid flow 29, 916–926..

instead of this:

Hwang, S.D., Kwon, H.G., Cho, H.H., 2008. Heat transfer with dimple/protrusion arrays in a rectangular duct with a low reynolds number range. International journal of heat and fluid flow 29, 916–926.

Indeed, I want to put "and" before the last author's name. How can do it?

the log and blg files:

[file](https://files.fm/u/fazeubbx)

Comment: Is `model2-names.bst` available somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in the elsaticle template files. elsarticle download link: https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip

Comment: No solution? Do you need help?

Comment: With the example you posted (minus a zillion of invisible control characters), I do get an "and" in front of the last author.

Comment: really? using the model2-names.bst?

Comment: Yes, from the link you posted. Can you add the .log file and .blg file?

Comment: Dear Sam. The files are attached in the edited version.

Comment: Unfortunately this web service is not available with an add blocker. Would you mind sharing them on another platform, for example https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: Please check it

Comment: OK, I can reproduce the issue now. I'll have a look if I can find some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an "and" before the last name, make a copy of the file `model2-names.bst`, rename it and change line 454 from

```
          "," *
```

to

```
          " " * bbl.and *
```

And in your .tex file, adjust `\bibliographystyle{model2-names}` to the new file name you choose.